How to use WMAPE for data sets with a large % of 0 values?
I work with data sets where 30-50% of the data has 0 values. These data points are excluded to ensure WMAPE can actually calculate, but I have concerns excluding that much of the data. When addressing forecast accuracy concerns in this case, WMAPE masks any instances where we may be over-forecasted at low-selling data intersections.
I have considered MAD which isn't ideal given weighting is important. I also looked at MASE but given the product being forecasted is highly seasonal and rarely exists for more than one season, I don't think MASE would work.
I can think of 2 other at least partial solutions-

Weight MAPE using forecast instead of sales- this seems like an easy fix as it would include all intersections with 0 sales that have a forecast, but I don't know what the downsides would be.
Increase the time frame for assessing WMAPE, e.g. grabbing the last 3 months of data instead of 1 month. I would lose a bit of specificity of the time frame, but this would greatly reduce the instances of 0 sales at the lower level.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!
